# How force jenkins to upload another jenkins file in project?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

Hello is it possible to work with two jenkins?
Jenkins slave do dirty job, and save image, then he upload to jenkins master. Or jenkins master download from slave. What would be the easiest way to do sthing like this?

ps. i dont know how tag this topic/help

---

edit1: I mean about working with two computers in the same network. 
I tried some with manage jenkins > new nodes but with no success. I will report if i will success.

---

edit2
Okay i set up slave to work by JWS, and tied to project. Then build project to refresh configuration. 
 Now i have problem with port listening by slave but i think i will have to ask admin to unlock. 
I gues unlock number which value is above 60.000.

I still don't know how use slave to do something and upload to master workspace /or/ use slave to save data in his temp and force master to grab this data from slave.
Ant suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: By slave and master, do you mean the computers, or two instances of Jenkins?

Comment: The answer really depends on what you're trying to achieve. Yes, it's possible to work with two jenkins, but the configuration and setup will all depend on what you need out of the system. What problem are you trying to fix by having two jenkins?

Comment: @sagar probably yes, i am new in it, trying grab everything with that problem

Comment: @Laepdjek master linux, slave windows xp x86. The main problem is run program on windows which save data. Then somehow "teleport" this data to master (linux) workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michal,

You don't need two instances of Jenkins to get information from the slave to the master. There are plugins for that.

===========================================================

There are two ways to add a Windows slave:

- by service
- by JNLP (this should work for sure)

Once you have a slave connected, install the following plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

===========================================================

Once this is done, set up two jobs. The first job runs on your slave (**restrict where this job is run**), and make it run your Windows XP program and store the image. Archive this file as an artifact.

On the second job, use the plugin above to copy the artifact from the first job, and use the data in the file as you need it.

For more information, look at the links below:

- Restricting jobs to a slave: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds
- Using the copy plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin
- Archiving an artifact: [Archive the artifacts in hudson/jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins) (the first picture in the question should be useful)

===========================================================

Comment: yes yes i've done the same yesterday, but thanks for a help :)