# Need to create a link for each Jenkins build so that user can download installer created by corresponding build

Tags: jenkins

I am able to create an installer using Jenkins. An installer is created for each build in "C:\Installer" of Server. I now want to be able to create 
a link on the page for each build so that the user should be able to click that link and download the installer they want.

I used DocLinks Plugin but had no luck.

I used the following configuration for DocLinks Plugin:

Title : Download Installer
Description : Downloads installer created by this build
Directory to archive : C:\Installer
Index file:

When I click on the Project Page I can see Document links which has Download Installer. but the link is not created. and when I click on the individual 
build, I don't see Document links display at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to add your installer in the `Archive artifacts` parameter ? Because it will publish a link for your installer on every build done. ([Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins) to better understand artifacts management)