# How to prevent overwriting outcome file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, unity-game-engine, perforce

I run an everyday build using Jenkins and Unity3d command line arguments

(Android build)

`-quit -batchmode -projectPath "$WORKSPACE" - executemode BuildSetup`

and (Windows build)

`-quit -batchmode -projectPath "$WORKSPACE" - "Artifacts/game.x86.exe" -logFile "$WORKSPACE\unity3d_editor  .`

Jenkins polls the SCM (Perforce) and starts to build automatically when I submit changes. Everything works fine but new outcome files (for instance “game.apk” for android) overwrites the old ones. I’d like to avoid overwriting files and keep the old ones as well. Other words - I’d like to get as much “game.apk” files as build successful finished.

Please help me out if you got any idea how to deal with it.

Thanks,
Adam.

Comment: postprocess script that copies the apk?

Comment: I would do it like @LearnCocos2D. It's only an easy cp-statement .and maybe you add a timestamp to the filenames while copying them to avoid similar filenames.

Comment: You could check your game.apk files into a Perforce server at the end of the build. Then Perforce would keep track of the versions of the game.apk files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "archive" your artifacts (what you called "outcome files").

It's a post-build action, called "Archive the Artifacts". Also, decide how many builds, with archives you want to keep. This is configured in the first "Advanced..." section of the job configuration.

More about archiving here:
[Archive the artifacts in hudson/jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins)

Comment: Glad that helped you, Adam. Since you are new to SO, I will respectfully explain that to *accept* an answer, you've got to click the *checkmark* icon outline  next to the answer (it will turn green).