# Understanding Jenkins' Archive The Artifacts and the use of it

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to understand what it does. Currently, this is the value that I see - dist/*.tgz*

From what I understand, our grunt scripts makes a tgz file. However, I don't know what Jenkins does.

I got an error when I didn't specify any pattern

```
ERROR: No artifacts are configured for archiving.
You probably forgot to set the file pattern, so please go back to the configuration and specify it.
If you really did mean to archive all the files in the workspace, please specify "**"
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Comment: Of course, when you enable it you need to add a pattern, click the *?* on the right side of it, it should explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, it allows you to archive items from your job's workspace in a persistent and accessible way, linked to the specific build number.

---

I.e. you have a job `Build` that compiles your sources into `program.exe`, archiving it linked to the build it was produced by, and keeping it accessible for developers or other jobs can come in very handy.

Additionally, archived artifacts are transferred to your jenkins master, so your job can run on any slave, but your archived files will be always accessible, even when that particular slave is offline.

Also, with the right configuration and plugins, other projects can access archived artifacts from other projects. I.e. a job `Deploy` that uploads your `program.exe` to some location is as trivial as copying the archived artifact of the last successful build into its workspace for the upload.

Theres quite some information on SO already, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins?rq=1).