# Different jenkins Build Folder for each day

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I am building a multi-project Project.
I want to ensure that the build directory is different for each day for each project and have to keep last 7 days of builds (if there are multiple builds in a day, it should keep it)
before running build, i want to delete all directories of builds that are 8 days or older.
Is there any plugin for that? if not, how to do that manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the "archive artifacts" function, and include all files you wish to keep.
You can configure how long the archived artifacts shall be stored. For example it can be set to keep the last 7 artifacts.

You can find further information here: [Archive the artifacts in hudson/jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins)