# Get Jenkins Master resources fromJenkins slave

Tags: jenkins

I'm building my java application in a slave but I would like to execute a shell script as post-build action, this script executes a specific module in my application and requires as parameter, cucumber report file(Json file) that is stored on the Jenkins master here:  /data/jenkins/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds.

how can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try a flow job for this which is also called as a DSL these days. check wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you archive the file that you need and the download it in the PBA?

Example:
[Archive the artifacts in hudson/jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

If this file is static you can add it to your Files under "manage jenkins",  and the in the post build you can "provide configuration file" using the post build plugin.