# Publish jenkins build results on website

Tags: jenkins

I need to get the results of my jenkins builds on my website. I already set up jenkins that when someone pushes on my repository the project will be build. Now I need the information if the build failed on my homepage, to enable/disable the download button. Theres the next question is it possible to get the latest build through jenkins?

I already found HTML Publisher Plugin but I dont think that this would solve my problem?

Best regards
John

Comment: Surely, if something doesn't build, you won't let people download it. Why can't they just download the old build if Jenkins fails?

Comment: yeah thats a good idea but i dont know how to put my project on my website to download. I thought jenkins could help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is traditionally done is with a build passing or failing icon, that lets users know that a build failed

[image: build passing]

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin

Comment: Thank you thats a great solution, is there a way that jenkins host my project that people can download it from my site?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do that. It really depends on the project though. It's often done by linking to the artifacts Jenkins build creates on its' server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-hudson-jenkins. Sometimes it's also done by a post script in jenkins that moves the build (if successful) to a download folder