# Jenkins Pipeline - file download operation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am quite new to `Jenkins`, and I am setting up a mobile build using the Jenkins-pipeline, which is working fine. Now this mobile-build generates an APK file, and I want to give an URL in the console to this generated APK file, so then whoever is triggering the build can download the APK file on a successful build.

I was checking [this plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/), but it doesn't fit in my use-case.

Is there any plugin available to do this file operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the archive artifact post build step, which saves the .apk file on the build console, making it available for download directly from the console.  Check this post speaking about [artifacts post step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821545/archive-the-artifacts-in-jenkins), and [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) in case you are using pipelines  .